# Backbone - Declare Default Parameters for a Fetch inside a Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have some global parameters that I want to be sent in every time I call a fetch on a collection... my issue is I don't want to declare the `data: { ... }` every time I fetch.

Is there a way I can provide default parameters inside the Collection itself with the possibility to add more or override some?

**For example:**

Instead of doing this every time:

```
this.articlesCollection.fetch({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        deviceType: GlobalVars.deviceType,
        memberId: GlobalVars.memberId,
        authToken: GlobalVars.authToken,
        targetObjectId: userId,
        limit: 50,
        excludeArticleBodies: true,
        excludeViewedItems: false
    },
    success: function() {
        _this.render();
    }
});
```

I'd like to just provide a one or two parameters and a success function, like this:

```
this.articlesCollection.fetch({
    data: {
        targetObjectId: userId
    },
    success: function() {
        _this.render();
    }
});
```

... and have the Collection look something like:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'global',
  'utilities',
  'models/article/ArticleModel'
], function(_, Backbone, GlobalVars, Utils, ArticleModel){

  var ArticlesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

      model: ArticleModel,

      initialize : function(view) {
          this.view = view;
      },

      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
          deviceType: GlobalVars.deviceType,
          memberId: GlobalVars.memberId,
          authToken: GlobalVars.authToken,
          limit: 50,
          excludeArticleBodies: true,
          excludeViewedItems: false
       },

      url : function() {
        return GlobalVars.baseAPIUrl + '/API/GetArticles';
      },

      parse : function(data) {  
        return data.Articles;
      }     

  });

  return ArticlesCollection;

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working jsFiddle with one approach:  http://jsfiddle.net/LEuGq/1/

Basically, you configure both an object of `defaultParams` and `params` as properties of your collection, which are used to dynamically compute the correct URL when `fetch()` is called. This way is probably more in alignment with backbone than changing the API of `fetch()` to accept parameters, which it is not designed to do.

```
var ParamCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    defaultParams: {deviceType: 'raceCar', limit: 42},
    params: {},
    url: function() {
      return "/paramcollection?" + $.param(_.defaults(this.params, this.defaultParams));
    }
});
var paramCollection = new ParamCollection();
paramCollection.params.excludeArticleBodies = true;
paramCollection.params.limit = 52;
$("#debug").append(paramCollection.url());
```

Comment: I know this is quite an old answer, but could you explain why it is that you use a separate object for `defaultParams` as opposed to setting some initial values within the  `params` object which can then be overridden?

Comment: Just for clarity of intent, but I think it would also work with a single `params` property.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone uses jQuery's `ajax` call by default, so you can set up anything you need as a default using various methods. See this question for some examples: [jQuery's ajaxSetup - I would like to add default data for GET requests only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996993/jquerys-ajaxsetup-i-would-like-to-add-default-data-for-get-requests-only)

Comment: I use this for some things, like cache, etc... but some of the variables I want to use are collection specific.