# In JQuery/Backbone, how can I override every AJAX request to add an additional parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, backbone.js

```
$.post('/js/register', data, function(){

});

$.get('/js/home', data, function(){
    //render the template here
});
```

I use these in my Backbone app.  It fetches the data from the server, then renders the template.

I want to override these on a global level so that when I make these calls, "data" has the current window.location (the url) as an attribute.

For EVERY ajax call, I want to append the current url that the user is currently on.

PS - I'm using Backbone push state - does that make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this answer should help you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/6998085/1846192

In your case:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  options.data = $.param($.extend(originalOptions.data, { url: window.location.href }));
});
```

Comment: I've edited the answer, just put it anywhere before any calls to `$.get()` or `$.post()`.